# Can VisualStudio adjust newline and formatting settings each time a file is opened?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm working with a small team, and we're fairly evenly split between the following styles:

```
public void Method() {
  // code
}
```

and:

```
public void Method()
{
  // code
}
```

I know we can each setup Visual Studio (2010 Professional) to place New Lines where we want them, but that's only at the time the code is authored.

Is it possible to have the code re-formatted when it's opened (or by running an External Tool?) to the current user's preference, or do we really need to have a long debate about the best style (or abandon any hope of consistent code)?

(note: I am NOT asking which style is best, please don't try answering that question. Just can we have VS eliminate the debate by automatically re-formatting existing code into the style preferred at the moment?)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an envrimental events macro to do just that.  This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165651.aspx) tells you how to create one of these macros.

```
Private Sub DocumentEvents_DocumentOpened(ByVal Document As EnvDTE.Document) Handles DocumentEvents.DocumentOpened
      DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.FormatDocument")
End Sub
```